# No overload matches this call. Typescript and StyledComponents in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby, styled-components

Ok, I keep running into this error message and I don't quite understand this.

Info : React: 16.12, Styled-components: 5.2.0, Gatsby with typescript: 4.0.2. I have @types for react and styled-components too.

Here is the component.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import WorkDisplayImage from "./WorkDisplayImage";

type WorkDisplayProps = {
  imageSource: string;
  imageAlt: string;
  linkToProject: string;
  linkToCode?: string;
  projectName: string;
  projectType: string;
  gridArea: string;
};

const StyledWorkDisplay = styled.a<WorkDisplayProps>` // <- I defined the type here.
  grid-area: ${(props): string => props.gridArea};
`;

const WorkDisplay = ({
  imageSource,
  imageAlt,
  linkToProject,
  linkToCode,
  projectName,
  projectType,
}: WorkDisplayProps): JSX.Element => (
  <StyledWorkDisplay href={linkToProject} target="noreferrer opener"> // <- But this component is underlined with the error.
    <WorkDisplayImage imageSource={imageSource} imageAlt={imageAlt} />
  </StyledWorkDisplay>
);

export default WorkDisplay;
```

Here is typescript's mess of an error message.

No overload matches this call.

> > Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes, HTMLAnchorElement>, "slot" | ... 262 more ... | "referrerPolicy"> & { ...; } & WorkDisplayProps, "slot" | ... 270 more ... | "gridArea"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 270 more ... | "gridArea"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
> > Type '{ children: Element; href: string; target: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes, HTMLAnchorElement>, "slot" | ... 262 more ... | "referrerPolicy"> & { ...; } & WorkDisplayProps, "slot" | ... 270 more ... | "gridArea"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 270 more ... | "gridArea">': imageSource, imageAlt, linkToProject, projectName, and 2 more.
> > Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"a", any, WorkDisplayProps, never>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"a", any, WorkDisplayProps, never>, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>', gave the following error.
> > Type '{ children: Element; href: string; target: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes, HTMLAnchorElement>, "slot" | ... 262 more ... | "referrerPolicy"> & { ...; } & WorkDisplayProps, "slot" | ... 270 more ... | "gridArea"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 270 more ... | "gridArea">': imageSource, imageAlt, linkToProject, projectName, and 2 more.

#### So, is typescript complaining because I'm not using all the props on the StyledWorkDisplay component, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to pass all not optional props you defined in `WorkDisplayProps`

However, it doesn't seem right to type your link with all the props of the parent, you could use a Pick to get only the one you're actually using

```
const StyledWorkDisplay = styled.a<Pick<WorkDisplayProps, 'gridArea'>>`
  grid-area: ${(props): string => props.gridArea};
`;

...
  projectName,
  projectType,
  gridArea,
}: WorkDisplayProps): JSX.Element => (
  <StyledWorkDisplay gridArea={gridArea} href={linkToProject} target="noreferrer opener">
...
```